# Can there be portals in the Astral Plane that lead to the Elemental Planes?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes, astral

In the spell description of Astral Projection (PHB pg 215) it indicates the following :

> Your astral form can freely travel through the Astral Plane and can
> pass through portals there **to any other plane**.

However, in the Astral Color Pools table (DMG pg 47) there are no color pools leading to the the Elemental Planes (or the Shadowfell or Feywild). The description of "color pools" refers to them as "gateways".

Finally, in the description of relevant planar travel spells (DMG pg 46) it indicates the following :

> And the astral projection spell lets adventurers project themselves
> into the Astral Plane **and from there travel to the Outer Planes**.

Accordingly, can there be portals in the Astral Plane that lead to the Elemental Planes?

Comment: Are you asking a lore question or are you asking if you can build your astral plane that way as a DM?

Comment: I think more as a lore question, but this is all new to me so either type of answer would be helpful.

Comment: Related: [Are there symbols representing the Feywild, the Shadowfell and elemental planes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/171939/48793)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### No, the Elemental Planes are not connected directly to the Astral Plane.

As you have noted, transit to other planes via the Astral Plane occurs via [Color Pools](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/creating-a-multiverse#ColorPools).

There 16 different types, none of which are the Elemental Planes.

However, you could transit from the Astral Plane to the Ethereal Plane via an Ethereal Plane color pool, and then from there to the Elemental Planes.  So, indirectly, but totally feasible.

It seems your question is somewhat related to whether it's reasonable to adjust it to work that way. If you as the DM just wished for there to be Elemental Plane Color Pools in the Astral Plane, that would be a reasonable adjustment to make, as it is already indirectly possible.

#### Do the Color Pools take you to the Deep Ethereal or Border Ethereal?

There is an [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/167480/42509) that touches on this.  To simplify it a bit, the Border Ethereal is the part of the Ethereal Plane that borders the Material Plane.  To get to the Deep Ethereal, you need stronger magic (Plane Shift, Gate or magical portal are the DMG's specific examples).

Getting to the Astral Plane is no small feat in itself.  In addition, the Astral Plane doesn't share a border with the Ethereal Plane like the Material Plane does.  With those two facts in mind it's reasonable to conclude that Color Pools in the Astral Plane would take you into the Deep Ethereal Plane.

Comment: So when you transit from the Astral to the Ethereal through a color pool, are you entering the Deep Ethereal which has the curtains leading to the Inner Planes? Or does it matter whether you are entering Deep or Border Ethereal? And if the Elemental Planes are not connected directly to the Astral Plane, does Astral Projection spell fail if it is cast in the Elemental Planes and the Material Echos (Shadowfell,Feywild)?

Comment: Good question, I updated my answer to include a response about the Color Pools since they were relevant to my answer.  I think the second question (about Astral Projection) is probably better answered in an actual second question.